# Working With Abstract Class

Tags: java

In java if there is an abstract class A, class B inheriting from A and if class B does not provide the implementation of any method of class A. Then could we create the object of class B?
CASE 2:
What will happen if class B provide implementation of some functions of class A. Then still could we create an object of class B?

Comment: No, and no. (Assuming you specifically meant abstract methods of class A.)

Comment: This is not a homework question and answer site.

Comment: Why don't you try yourself and see what happen? vote to close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its depends upon Class A :

1. If class A does not have any abstract method then class B can instantiated, No issue.
2. If class A having abstract method then class B need to give implementation of each abstract method (in this case also class B can be substantiated) otherwise B itself be abstract.

   if class B making itself abstract it can't be instantiated.

Answer (score 1):

What's inside class A?

If class B is concrete, it needs to implement all abstract methods from class A, otherwise it will not compile.

If class B is abstract you can't instantiate it at all.

The rule is:

> If class B inherits from abstract class A, it must implement all abstract methods from A in order to be concrete. Otherwise, B must be marked as abstract too.

PS: I see you are new to SO, please read the best practices here before posting a question.

Answer (score 1):

**1** No. And Class B would also have to be abstract (or you'd get a compiler error).

**2** If by some, you mean all of the abstract methods, then yes. If by some, you mean a subset of the abstract methods - then no and see answer **1**.